# Scroll to a point in a wordpress designed website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a website which is designed in wordpress. In my one page i have a form included which is

```
[contact-form-7 id="144" title="Contact Form"]
```

No from one page i want to redirect to this particular id, for which i am writing

```
<href="http:my_url/contact#144"> which is not working
```

i have also tried

```
<href="http:my_url/contact.php#144"> but giving me page not found 404 error.
```

So what i am doing wrong that i am not able to detect.

Comment: If you want to scroll to an ID, it needs to be on a <a> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ID is only the ID of the form you're pulling in, referenced internally by the plugin - it isn't output on the element itself. If you go into the inspector, it'll be something like wpcf7-f482-p481-o1, only with different letters/numbers after wpcf7. If you want to make a prettier link, just wrap the embed code in a div with an ID of your choosing and use that on the anchor.

Comment: Thanks.. I am able to understand what i was doing wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on a contact form 7 id.

Try:

```
<div id="cForm">
    [contact-form-7 id="144" title="Contact Form"]
</div>
```

Then link to with `<a href="http:my_url/contact#cForm">Contact form</a>`